# Temperature coefficient of a voltage source

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, temperature, voltage-measurement, voltage-reference

1. Is the temperature coefficient of a voltage source related to the internal resistance of the voltage source?
2. Why does the voltage increase/decrease when the temperature is increased or decreased?
3. In case of a band-gap reference, how is this temp coefficient related to the change of temperature to get the PTAT and CTAT? The figure below shows 2 dependencies and I didn't understand from where the temperature coefficient comes in order to cancel the linear effect of the sources.

[image]

Comment: 1) No, because off-load the voltage would look constant if it were related to the internal (series) resistance. 2) Chemistry, drift, imprecision, by design......

Comment: The causes of the dependencies are explained by the field of *Solid State Physics*. The way the dependencies are exploited is explained in [this patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/7e/bd/db/925cdc20a3c08d/US3617859.pdf) and [this paper](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~abonacci/ee222/Images/JSSC_Brokaw.pdf), for example.